# Flywaydb integration

Tags: java, maven, flyway

I am trying to integrate Flyway migration into my project (portlet - maven build) but I cannot figure out how to do all the necessary steps - could you please take a look on what I have done so far and advice what am I missing, please? I read the documentation and some examples but there is no complete tutorial how to set it up from scratch:

Here is what I have done:

1) Added dependencies in pon.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.flyway</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.21</version>
</dependency>
```

2) Added sql script V1_Create_table_messages.sql in src/main/resources/db/migration

```
CREATE TABLE messages (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    msgid VARCHAR(64) UNIQUE,
    sender VARCHAR(255),
    receiver VARCHAR(255),
);
```

3) Created migration class with this:

```
 public void migrate() {
        try {       
            Flyway flyway = new Flyway();

            flyway.setDataSource("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDb", "user", "password");

            flyway.setInitOnMigrate(true);
            flyway.migrate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error while migrate database");
        }
    }
```

When I call this method, I get this: (EDITed!)

```
com.googlecode.flyway.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to obtain Jdbc connection from DataSource
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid authorization specification message from server: "Access denied for user 'nobody'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"
```

All the information in setDataSource are set correctly. I know its probably something dumb, but I feel I am missing some important step in setting up Flyway here...

Thanks for any tips!

EDIT2:
Added MySQL connector dependency in pom.xml

SOLVED:

the problem was missing mysql dependency and extra slash in url...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `migrate()` method. You set the data source twice.

```
flyway.setDataSource("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDb", "user", "password");
```

and

```
flyway.setDataSource(dataSource);
```

I would guess that the second `setDataSource()` overwrites the correct first data source.

**EDIT**

The correct POM definition to use the MySQL Java Connector instead of H2 would be:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.30</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thats right, I forgot co delete this line.. however, There is still some problem... I will edit my question

Comment: I checked the way I use Flyway and it's pretty much exactly the same you have. Are you sure the data source is reachable? `Access denied for user 'nobody'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

Comment: When I use JDBC natively in my protlet, I use the same configuration for working with my db and I had no problem so far...

Comment: Are you connecting to MySQL or to H2 as the dependency in your POM suggests? Your JDBC URL might need to be `jdbc:h2:myDb`? Or your POM might need to contain `mysql-connector-java`?

Comment: I am connecting to MySQL database on localhost - perhaps the dependency in POM is incorrect...

Comment: The code you posted runs fine on my machine. There must be still a problem with the JDBC URL string, or the DataSource set.

Comment: You were right... I was creating the url via code and there was one extra slash in the url which somehow caused the problem...