# FlywayDB, Unable to connect to the sql server, recv failed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, jdbc, flyway, jtds

I am trying to use **FlywayDB 3.2.1** as a migration aid to my Database. I am using the default jtds driver that comes along.

```
Machine : Windows 8
SQL Server : sql-server 2012
```

Using the same driver jar when i write a test java code it connects to the database, no exceptions thrown.

I use the same jdbc url i.e `jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:49220/SAMPLE_DB` @ flyway.conf i.e:

```
flyway.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:49220/SAMPLE_DB
```

I get the following error while i use the command flyway migrate

> ERROR: Unable to obtain Jdbc connection from DataSource
>   (jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:49220/SAMPLE_DB) for user
>   'bbudhathoki': I/O Error: Software caused connection abort: recv
>   failed

TCP Connection has been enabled 
I get port 49220 from the following

```
USE master
GO
xp_readerrorlog 0, 1, N'Server is listening on' 
GO
```

Comment: Please visit the links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22981967/flywaydb-integration or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035785/java-error-software-caused-connection-abort-recv-failed.